# Junit Test suite without creating empty class

Tags: java, junit

I have tree test classes

```
class Test1 {........ //some tests ... } 
class Test2 {..... //Some Tests.... } 
class Test3 {....//Some tests.... }
```

and to create test suite i created

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({Test1.class,
        Test2.class,
        Test3.class})
public class MyTestSuite { 
}
```

now this test suite is  empty.

Is there way we do NOT create empty class and directly give Test1 , Test2 and Test3 class annotation that its is a part of MyTestSuite class ?

Comment: Put your annotations on Test1, say?

Comment: Yes, can we do that ? if yes then what is the right syntax for that ?

Comment: Just add all the lines before public class to Test1, before public class...

Comment: Do you know JUnit's Categories feature? https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Categories

Comment: @JPMoresmau thanks for quick response. If we add all the lines before public class to Test1 class i would give " contains itself as a SuiteClass" error. Which dose not seems to work !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot. Class is needed, otherwise how your compiler know what to compile. In java the syntax of enum or class must exist in the java file or you will not able to run the program. The empty class for the test suite is just a holder for the program to compile.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yep seems like, there is no other option  but to create empty class.